# Which index the dataloader is chosing

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am using torch.utils.data.DataLoader. like
`train_features, train_labels = next(iter(train_dataloader))` I want to determine which index the trainer is chosen?
`for batch_idx, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):` can index from 0, but if we shuffle, can we know the indices for this batch?

Comment: Do you mean the index from the original dataset? You could write a custom dataloader to do this for you.

Comment: The simple answer is no. But if you want to, there's a hard way to do it. Let's say your data is an image. You can pass a pandas data frame consist of column = ["image id", "image path", "label"] as a dataset. Then on the loader, you can read those image id